# What is the correct way to send large CSV Files to Server using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSV file with ~20,000 records. I send each line using the `$.post` method to my server using the FileReader API.

The problem is that the browser is buffering each record before starting to send the data and this way is very slow. I want to send each line separately to show a progressbar where it counts the request number of each line.

As this solution is very slow I'm thinking there are must be other ways of doing this to make it faster. Many thanks to your ideas.

```js
$("#form_file").change(function(e) {
  if (e.target.files != undefined) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
      var index = rows[0];
      index = index.split(";");
      gesamt = rows.length - 1;

      for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        cells = row.split(";");
        var dataset = {};

        for (var ii = 0; ii < cells.length; ii++) {
          var value = cells[ii];
          var key = index[ii]
          var printError = function(error, explicit) {
            console.log(`[${explicit ? 'EXPLICIT' : 'INEXPLICIT'}] ${error.name}: ${error.message}`);
          }

          try {
            dataset[key] = value;            
          } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof RangeError) {
              if (e.message.toLowerCase().indexOf('invalid array') !== -1) {
                printError(e, true);
              } else {
                printError(e, false);
              }
            } else {
              printError(e, false);
            }
          }
        }

        console.log(dataset);
        row = insertrow(dataset, i);
        $('#progressbar').show();
        $('#progressvalue').text(i + '/' + gesamt);
        $('#progresstitle').text('(' + dataset.title + ')');
      }
    };
    var test = reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
  }
});

function insertrow(mydata, step) {
  var token = "{{app.request.query.get('_token')}}";
  mydata = JSON.stringify(mydata);
  $.post('preferences/upload?_token=' + token, {
    data: mydata
  }, function(data) {
    $('#info').show();
    var html = data.message + '<br />';
    $('#info').append(html);
  }, "json");
}
```

Comment: Right now your code is flooding your server with 20,000 requests in a fraction of a second. That is a bad idea and is not a workable solution. Send the whole file at once and loop through it on the server. If you want the client to be kept up to date with the progress through the file, use a websocket connection.

Comment: yes, the 20000 requests are exactly the problem. i will figure out your idea and post the better solution after trying this. thx. (ive thought there are another idea by sending each line separately :) )